# "Upgrade to Windows 11" prompt showing on Windows 11's Windows Upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I updated to Windows 11 from windows 10, but on the Windows Update section in the Settings app I still get the "Upgrade to Windows 11" prompt. What can I do?

Windows Update screenshot:

[image: Windows Update screenshot]

**EDIT (May 06 2022):** Since I had other problems with my Windows installation, I finally decided to reset my PC; since it didn't work, I backed-up my data and fresh installed from ISO/USB.

Comment: That is kinda funny. It says "Pending download" so just let it download (with the Download Now button) then when it is finished downloading and installing. restart your pc.

Comment: Yeah, tried to do that, but after a while it'll show up again...

Comment: Get WhyNotWin11 from GitHub and run it to verify all is well with your computer. Then make the Windows 11 ISO on a USB Key from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11 and run Setup on the USB key.

Comment: I haven't got a USB key right now, I'll try it as soon as i get one...

Comment: @develc - You don't need a USB key.  You can mount the ISO and run Setup.exe from the mounted ISO.  However, I have no idea why the suggestion to run the Windows 11 setup has been made, it's likely not even applicable to your situation.  My suggestion would be to perform a Windows Update reset to clear the cache.

Comment: Hi, than you all for your replies. I have tried to install with USB but I understand that doing so would erase all my data. I also tried to run iso disk's SETUP.EXE, but it said that "Installation has failed.". I'll google to find out how to reset Windows Update/clear the cache

Comment: Hi I just noticed that winver.exe in the photo reports verison '''21h2''' but I thought that Windows 11 should report '''22h2'''...

Comment: Furthermore, I can't update to the latest Windows 11 Feature Update (failing with error code 0x800f081f) and maybe that's all because my Windows Update thinks I am still on Windows 10

Comment: (I am no sure about anything of this, just making some hypothesis)